# How to do a DB reverse lookup with Akka Persistence in Lagom?

Tags: scala, akka, lagom

I'm building a token authentication microservice using `Lagom`, and have run into a wrinkle.  My data model is currently

```
table Token (
  groupName varchar(255) PK,
  token varchar(255) (logical UUID type)
)
```

I have three methods, `createToken`, `getToken`, and `validateToken`.  The first two take a group name, which maps nicely to the entity id as laid out in https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/current/scala/PersistentEntity.html#Persistent-Entity.
The third takes a token in the body of the request, and then returns a json payload with the `groupName` and `token` if it succeeds.

Lagom abstracts the actual SQL, and you access the persistence layer by doing something like this: `val ref = persistentEntityRegistry.refFor[DptokenEntity](groupName)`.  The actual persistence code is this here:

```
class DptokenEntity extends PersistentEntity {

  override type Command = DptokenCommand[_]
  override type Event = DptokenEvent
  override type State = DptokenState

  override def initialState: DptokenState = DptokenState(None)

  override def behavior: Behavior = {
    case DptokenState(_) => Actions()
      .onCommand[PersistToken, TokenResponse] {
      case (PersistToken(token), ctx, state) =>
        ctx.thenPersist(TokenPersisted(token)) { _ =>
          ctx.reply(token)
        }
    }.onReadOnlyCommand[GetToken, TokenResponse] {
      case (GetToken(groupName), ctx, state) =>
        state.token match {
          case Some(token) => ctx.reply(token)
          case None => ctx.invalidCommand(s"No token exists for $groupName")
        }
    }.onEvent {
      case (TokenPersisted(token), _) => DptokenState(Some(token))
    }
  }
}

case class DptokenState(token: Option[TokenResponse])
```

I am struggling to understand how to do the reverse look up with the above model due to the fact that if I lookup the `entity` by the token, I will ostensibly get a new row in the database where the relationship is `token` -> `groupName`, which then poses massive problems for updates, etc...

I wanted to check with the good folks on SO before I just rip out the Event Sourcing stuff and use raw Slick.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, that you need CQRS and Lagom Persistent Entity?
If you need to implement a case for finding your entity by `token`, you need to use Read-Side for this. But I'm not sure, that Lagom PE is the right choice for you. Try to use basic [PersistentActor](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence.html) instead of Lagom PE.